# PyGTK Multiprocessing and Updating GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, pygtk, multiprocessing

I am trying to enable and disable a stop button for audio playback in a GUI created using Glade PyGTK 2.0.

The program basically works by running and external process to play the audio.

I am using multiprocessing(as threading is too slow) and I can't get the stop button to disable. I understand this is due to processes not being able to access the memory shared by the gtk widget thread.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there any way to enable the button once the process exits?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygtk
import multiprocessing
import gobject
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk
import threading

gtk.threads_init()

class Foo:
    def __init__(self): 
        #Load Glade file and initialize stuff

    def FooBar(self,widget):
        self.stopButton.set_sensitive(True)#make the Stop button visible in the user section
        def startProgram():
            #run program
            gtk.threads_enter()
            try:
                self.stopButton.set_sensitive(False) 
            finally:
                gtk.threads_leave()
            print "Should be done now"

        thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=startProgram)
        thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
prog = Foo()
gtk.threads_enter()
gtk.main()
gtk.threads_leave()
```

**EDIT:** Never mind, I figured it out. I had not implemented threading properly and that caused the lag. It works fine now. Just have to change the FooBar method to:

```
    def FooBar(self,widget):
        self.stopButton.set_sensitive(True)#make the Stop button visible in the user section
        def startProgram():
            #run program
            Popen.wait() #wait until process has terminated
            gtk.threads_enter()
            try:
                self.stopButton.set_sensitive(False) 
            finally:
                gtk.threads_leave()
            print "Should be done now"

        thread = threading.Thread(target=startProgram)
        thread.start()
```

Comment: How does the thread execute? Does it reach the `print`-statement? And if so, how does the traceback look like if there is one when the `set_sensitive(False)` is invoked if it's not within a `try`?

Comment: The thread does reach the print statement. and setting set_sensitive(False) outside the try catch block doesn't change anything(i.e does nothing)

Comment: Another check: Your comment to the `set_sensitive(True)` says "make ... visible", but `set_sensitive` isn't changing visibility (`hide`/`show` does) ... so just so it's not that: The button is visible all the way but it's just sensitivity you wish to toggle?

Comment: Yeah I want to toggle the sensitivity, not the visibility ,i.e enable/disable button and not hide/show it. It works fine outside the startProgram function. Is there anyway I can wait, for the created process to exit, without freezing the GUI?

Comment: You should be able to create a callback function with `gobject` (e.g. with http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add) and pass `thread` to it. Then just let the callback check if your thread is still alive with `thread.is_alive()` (if not just set a new callback).