# Activating and Disabling button after process in python and pyGTK

Tags: python, pygtk, popen

Essentially, I am trying to make a button "active" first, run a process, and then after that process has finished running, disable the button again.

Using pyGTK and Python, the code in question looks like this...

```
self.MEDIA_PLAYER_STOP_BUTTON.set_sensitive(True) #Set button to be "active"
playProcess = Popen("aplay " + str(pathToWAV) + " >/dev/null 2>&1",shell=True) #Run Process
playProcess.wait() #Wait for process to complete    
self.MEDIA_PLAYER_STOP_BUTTON.set_sensitive(False) #After process is complete, disable the button again
```

However, this does not work at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this just http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933970/pygtk-multiprocessing-and-updating-gui that was posted the other day?

Answer (score 1):

All is working normally (python 2.7.3). But if you call playProcess.wait() in gui thread - you freeze gui thread without redrawing (sorry, my english isn`t very well). And are you sure that you try to use subprocess.popen()? Maybe os.popen()?

My small test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygtk, gtk, gtk.glade
import subprocess

def aplay_func(btn):
        btn.set_sensitive(True)
        print "init"
        playProcess = subprocess.Popen("aplay tara.wav>/dev/null 2>&1", shell=True)
        print "aaa"
        playProcess.wait()
        print "bbb"
        btn.set_sensitive(False)

wTree = gtk.glade.XML("localize.glade")
window = wTree.get_widget("window1")
btn1 = wTree.get_widget("button1")
window.connect("delete_event", lambda wid, we: gtk.main_quit())
btn1.connect("clicked", aplay_func)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Result:

```
init
aaa
bbb
```

And yes, button is working correctly. Sound too.